# How can I keep file attachment windows (e.g. Gmail in Chrome) from going behind the Dock so I can't click OK or Cancel?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, dock

When a file attachment window for Gmail in Chrome pops up, it goes behind the dock and it is really difficult to hit cancel - I can do it, but only the very top part of the button.

[image: screenshot]

The window can't be moved because it is a pop-up. Is there a way to keep this from happening? My example is Gmail, but I think it has happened in other instances, too.

I am using OS X 10.9.2 on a 2012 MacBook Pro and Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the Dock using ⌥⌘D, then drag the bottom of the pane upwards. Unhide the Dock with the same keyboard shortcut, then interact with the pane normally. The pane should remember its size for next time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That solution works perfectly.